# changes in 1 controller are not visible in 2 controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop-down list

```
<md-option ng-repeat="person in people" ng-value="person">
    {{ profile.lastname }}
</md-option>
```

I change its value to 1 controller

```
function savePerson(lastname) {

}
```

saving works, refreshes the drop down list,
but as we move to another controller, the value in the drop-down list returns to the previous one.

I want the list to always be refreshed.

How to pass the value of the list to another controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can make set/get function in the service to communicate data between two controllers.

**Service: [Ex: Service1]**

```
var data = {};

function setData(newData) {
   data = newData;
}

function getData() {
   return data;
}
```

**controller 1:**

Set data into service after getting data

```
Service1.setData(newData);
```

**controller 2:**

Use that data:

```
var getNewData = Service1.getData();

console.log("getNewData:", getNewData);
```

**Hope this answer solve your problem. Let me know if you are facing any problem.**